# Copy vim messages into clipboard

Tags: error, os-clipboard

When I'm confronting a bug of a plugin and an error message pops up like this one:

```
E5018: Error executing lua ...
```

and if I want to report this bug, I always have to type this error message manually. How can I copy the error message into my clipboard in order to paste it on github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can typically see the error messages produced by plug-ins using the `:messages` command.

If you'd like to put those messages into a Vim buffer, so that you can copy them to the clipboard from there, you can use the following command:

```
:put =execute('messages')
```

This uses the `execute()` function to capture output of an Ex command, then the expression register `"=` to use that in a register context and finally the `:put` command to append the contents of that register to the current buffer.

See `:help :messages`, `:help execute()`, `:help "=` and `:help :put` for more details.

Comment: Or `let @* = execute('messages')`; very clever idea

Answer (score 2):

I combined @filbranden's answer with the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474914/how-to-copy-the-error-message-when-vim-start

and came up with this leader shortcut that copies the last message displayed by Vim to the clipboard - uses @D.BenKnoble's suggestion from the comments:

```
nnoremap <leader>m :let @*=trim(execute('1messages')) \| echo 'copied' <cr>
```

Comment: How about `nnoremap <leader>m :let @* = trim(execute('1messages')) <bar> echo 'copied'<cr>` (the main difference is the `<bar>`)?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I like your version better but for some reason I can't get it to work. When I try to save my my `.vimrc` I get `E121: Undefined variable: cr` - I can't figure out why `<cr>` is accepted in my version but not yours. btw I'm using MacVim, maybe it's a subtle difference

Comment: You could try with caps `<CR>`, but I also forgot I had to escape the `|`

Comment: ahh, escaping `|` is what made it work - didn't matter whether `<CR>` was capitalized. will update the answer